# Move .onChange() to its own place so I don't repeat it so many times

Tags: swift, swiftui

I hate repeating code and I'm currently doing it, how can I put the snippet below into another... view? so that I can call it instead of writing all that? The reason why I have all that logic in a view instead of a viewmodel is because of environment state:

```
.onChange(of: walletDataStoreHandlerViewModel.walletsReceivedNewValue) { newValue in
    if(walletDataStoreHandlerViewModel.reloadingWallets == false) {
        walletDataStoreHandlerViewModel.reloadingWallets = true
        print(" Reloading wallet....")
        
        Task {
            try await walletDataStoreHandlerViewModel.getUserWallets(user: user)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fast idea how to decrease the amount of code: create a separate `ViewModifier`:

```
struct WalletUpdater: ViewModifier {

   let walletVM: YourWalletVMType

   func body(content: Content) -> some View {
      content
         .onChange(of: walletVM.walletsReceivedNewValue) { newValue in
            // your code of updating
         }
   }
}
```

The example of usage:

```
//..
VStack {
   // something
}
.modifier(WalletUpdater(walletVM: walletDataStoreHandlerViewModel)
```

P.S. Additionally you can create a `View extension`

Comment: Woops! That's a modifier I always needed and I seemed to have skipped in my learning process lol Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer provided works, It does emphasize that it is a **fast** idea. That being said, you should probably not have your logic in the view, rather move it into a ViewModel. Refactoring your code will help you long term, **especially if this is a project that you want to scale**.

This can help: https://www.swiftyplace.com/blog/swiftui-and-mvvm

Comment: looking into it